# How I scan all the IP-Addresses range/s?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In MainActivity top I added array variable:

```
private final String[] ipaddresses = new String[]{
            "http://10.0.0.1:8098/?cmd=nothing",
            "http://10.0.0.3:8098/?cmd=nothing",
            "http://10.0.0.2:8098/?cmd=nothing"};
```

Then with a button click I use a `for loop` to iterate over each `IP address`.
I check with a web server on my PC on which IP the PC is sitting.
I send a command to the server and get back a result.

The question is, how I can build an array with all the logic available IP addresses?
Since my PC can be sometimes on IP 10.0.0.2 and when I restart the pc or move to another PC the IP can be something else like 10.0.0.3

This is the button code where I also loop over the IPs

```
public void addListenerOnButton()
    {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)

                        {

                                try
                                {
                                    response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    String err = e.toString();
                                }

                                if (response!=null)
                                {



                                    try
                                    {
                                        final String a = new String(response,"UTF-8");




                                        text.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                text.setText(a);
                                            }
                                        });

                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("encoding exception");
                                    }

                                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("test1");
                                    break;

                                }

                                else
                                {

                                }

                            text.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    text.setText("Connection Failed");
                                }
                            });



                        }

                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

    }
```

New class:

```
package com.test.webservertest;

/**
 * Created by bout0 on 8/4/2015.
 */
public class IpAddresses
{
        private static String ipMain = "10.0.0.";
        private static int minIpRange = 0;
        private static int maxIpRange = 255;
        private static String[] ipAddresses = new String[maxIpRange];

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int i = minIpRange; i < maxIpRange; i++) {
                String ipRange = ipMain + i;
                //IP range in Array
                //ipAddresses[i] = ipRange;

                //if you need full IP range in Url, then unmark the following 2 lines and mark above line
                String UrlRange = "http://" + ipRange + ":8098/?cmd=nothing";
                ipAddresses[i] = UrlRange;
            }

            //testing array results
            for (int i = minIpRange; i < maxIpRange; i++)
                System.out.println(ipAddresses[i]);
        }

}
```

Comment: So you want to generate array of range of ip address from 10.0.0.2 til10.0.0.255

Comment: maytham right. From 10.0.0.2 or from the lowest available to the highest. I mean to cover all the possible ip addresses my pc might be on if i will restart or shut down my pc.

Comment: ok, i will try to make you one

Comment: So it is done. enjoy

Comment: On a side note: You could save yourself some time and look into a local dns server. Then you can reference machines by name instead of IP, and if the IP changes, the dns server takes care of that behind the scenes. Dnsmasq is highly suggestible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
public class IpRange {
    private static String ipMain = "10.0.0.";
    private static int minIpRange = 2;
    private static int maxIpRange = 255;
    private static String[] ipAddresses = new String[maxIpRange];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = minIpRange; i < maxIpRange; i++) {
            String ipRange = ipMain + i;
            //IP range in Array
            ipAddresses[i] = ipRange;

            //if you need full IP range in Url, then unmark the following 2 lines and mark above line
            //String urlRange = "http://" + ipRange + ":8098/?cmd=nothing";
            //ipAddresses[i] = urlRange;
        }

        //testing array results
        for (int i = minIpRange; i < maxIpRange; i++)
            System.out.println(ipAddresses[i]);
    }
}
```

IP addresses range in Array

```
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4
10.0.0.5
etc.
```

Or the output will be like this as complete Url if required (just modify the code as noted):

```
http://10.0.0.2:8098/?cmd=nothing
http://10.0.0.3:8098/?cmd=nothing
http://10.0.0.4:8098/?cmd=nothing
http://10.0.0.5:8098/?cmd=nothing
http://10.0.0.6:8098/?cmd=nothing
etc.
```

**Note:** the class is made for demonstration and is just example how this task can be achieved, it is up the individual to modified it and implement it in the relative code, to fulfill the final requirement.

---

**EDIT**
I have since optimized the code here is updated version:

```
public class IpRange {
    private String ipMain = "10.0.0.";
    private int startRange = 2; // 2 = 10.0.0.2
    private int endRange = 5;   // 5 = 10.0.0.5
    private int ipRangeLength = endRange - startRange;
    private String urlParam = ":8098/?cmd=nothing";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IpRange ipRange = new IpRange();

        // true -> ip range url with parameters / false -> only ip range
        String[] results = ipRange.ipRangeGenerator(true);

        for (String output : results)
            System.out.println(output);

    }

    public String[] ipRangeGenerator(boolean link) {
        String[] ipAddresses = new String[ipRangeLength];
        String urlRange;

        for (int i = 0; i < ipRangeLength; i++) {
            String ipRange = ipMain + (startRange + i);
            urlRange = ipRange;
            if (link)
                urlRange = "http://" + ipRange + urlParam;
            ipAddresses[i] = urlRange;
        }
        return ipAddresses;
    }

}
```

Comment: I hope you have fix your method call, this was a test class for demonstration, I assumed that you will implement it in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Generating a set of IP Addresses from 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.255 is as simple as iterating through the list of valid digits for the last segment:

```
List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
int min = 0;
int max = 255;
for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    String address = "10.0.0." + i;
    addresses.add(address);
}
```

Now the `addresses` list has all of the valid IP addresses in it. What addresses are generated can be tweaked by adjusting the min and max values to shrink the available range of addresses.